# Insert image on first occurence

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a xml document which looks something like this:

```
<chapter>
    <para>Just a random text<cross-ref refid="1234">Abb. 1.0</cross-ref>Some more text</para>
    <section-title>Title</section-title>
    <para>and more text text ext<cross-ref refif="1234">Abb 1.0</cross-ref>more more more</para>
</chapter>
```

As you can see there are two `cross-ref` elements inside paragraphs. They can occur basically everywhere and are somewhat identified by their `refid`(but not uniquely). What i am currently trying to do is inserting an image (based on the `refid`) at the position of the first occurence while keeping the text as a caption. Every other occurence (which are not the first) should just be inline texts containing an internal basic-link to that inserted image.
My current solution is:

```
  <xsl:template match="cross-ref">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
        <fo:block text-align="center" id="{@refid}">
          <xsl:variable name="refVar" select="@refid"/>
          <xsl:variable name="imageName" select="/chapter/floats/figure[@id=$refVar]/link/@locator" />
          <fo:external-graphic src="url({concat($imageName, '.jpg')})" />
          <fo:block text-align="center" xsl:use-attribute-sets="lit-para">
            <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
          </fo:block>
        </fo:block>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
        <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{@refid}">
          <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
        </fo:basic-link>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

It does work on some cases, but since `position()` is not always 1 some images are not getting inserted correctly. What are my options?
Thank you!

EDIT: I should clarify. The image should get inserted at the first occurence of a "new" `refid`. Thus. Each `refid` only has one image and every other `cross-ref`element with the same `refid` points to that image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the test in your `xsl:when`, so that it is true only for the first occurrence of each `@ref-id` value; in other words, you have to check that no preceding `cross-ref` element has the same `@ref-id`:

```
<xsl:when test="not(preceding::cross-ref[@ref-id = current()/@ref_id])">
...
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Another question if you have the time: Do you know how to append an image to the parent (or the end of the current block) of the current selected element instead of just directly at the current position (i.e. inside the text)

Comment: In StackOverlow, you should open a new question to ask something new. Do not extend your current question with more questions. It is a site where people learn from other questions and your second question would never be located.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 3.0, if you add an `xsl:key` as a top-level element:

```
<xsl:key name="cross-ref" match="cross-ref" use="@refid" />
```

then you can change your `xsl:when` to:

```
<xsl:when test=". is key('cross-ref', @refid)[1]">
```

This works because `key()` returns nodes in document order (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#keys).  This is potentially quicker (on large documents) than using the `preceding` axis, but to be sure you'd have to test it by running on your documents with your XSLT processor.

If you're using XSLT 1.0, you'd have to do it using a Meunchian Grouping-like trick:

```
<xsl:when test="count(. | key('cross-ref', @refid)[1]) = 1">
```

but that is much less readable than the XSLT 2.0 version.